# Using configuration of another project inside class library in .NET (not .NET Framework)

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-5

I have to rewrite the old .NET Framework project to the .NET 5 version. I have a web site based on ASP.NET Web Pages and a DLL project for this site - both .NET Framework 4.x. In the DLL project there is a code like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

As I understand, DLL project takes the needed config information from the web project's web.config file (or no matter what config file, if this DLL is used inside another project), because they are both used inside the same domain. But in the .NET 5 version there is no ConfigurationFile property in the SetupInformation. As far as I know, in .NET 5 you can obtain such an information from json settings or configuration files.

The question is - what is the best way to obtain inside DLL project such an information as aforementioned configuration file of another project that is located within the same domain, but in the .NET 5 world? And from the DLL point of view I don't know the name of a config file. The DLL in the .NET Framework world can use config data without this information.

Comment: I would rewrite the dll to take it's configuration as an injected dependency. By the way, if you're going to do a rewrite you should consider.NET 6 which is the long term support release.

Comment: I thought about this also, but need an example how to do it for the case of using the same settings.json or config.json file between the various projects that will be loaded inside the same domain. And I can't use .NET 6 because of decision of my superiors, but as I think the approach is almost the same as for .NET 5, so the solution for .NET 6 will suit me also.